# ssh from A to C over B with one command?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

There are three machines: A, B and C.

`C` is connected to a local port on `B`, so that `B` can access `C` anytime.

I would now like to connect to `C` from `A` (over `B`). What I currently do is logging in into `B` first via ssh like this:

`ssh user@B -i <identity_file>`

and then connect to `C`, like this

`ssh -o HostKeyAlias=<hostname_of_C> -p <some_port> <username_of_C>@localhost`

which is a bit inconvenient.

**Is there a way to directly connect with one command from A to C if I know the port?**